# Create and Load index.ios.bundle remotely

Tags: ios, bundle, react-native

I try to create `React-Native` app in `Side-By-Side` mode (already has a native `iOS` app and would like to add new stuff in `React-Native`).

But, I try to load the React-Native code remotely, e.i The app won't load the from localhoas like this: `http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle`, it'll load it from my server, e.g: `http://my_remote_server.com/public/index.ios.bundle`.

The problem I try to solve is to generate what the `React-Native` expected to get as an input `index.ios.bundle` but I can't generate `.bundle` file, only edit a `.js` file and the `React-Native` process it and create a `.bundle` file.

How can I configure my server to serve `React-Native` files?

Thanks in advance.